# Python objects and tree- AttributeError which i cant understand and tree appearing in wrong window

Tags: python, database, class, object, tree

I have created two windows in tkinter and created my own classes. The first window has a button which calls another child window. The second child window show display a list of all the products in a database that i have made. The problem is I get a AttributeError: 'EnterProducts' object has no attribute 'tree'. 
and the tree seems to be displayed in the first window rather than the second.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3


class Main():


    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('200x200+100+100')
        self.master.title('Menu')
        ttk.Style().configure("RB.TButton", background='blue', fg ='blue')

        self.MainLabel=Label(self.master,text='IT Sales',fg='Blue', font=("Rage Italic", 44)).grid (row = 0, column = 4)

        self.Products=ttk.Button(self.master,text="Products",width = 20, command=self.Products, style="RB.TButton").grid (row = 1, column = 4)

    def Products(self):
        root1=Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI1=EnterProducts(root1)
        self.master.geometry('800x500+100+100')


    def finish(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    class EnterProducts():

    def __init__(self,master):

        db_name = 'sales.db'

        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('400x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('Product Details')
        self.MainLabel = Label(self.master,text='All Products',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=W)

        self.Products=ttk.Button(self.master,text="Products",width = 20, command="", style="RB.TButton").grid (row = 1, column = 4)
        self.viewing_records()


    def run_query (self, query, parameters = ()): 


        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return query_result

    def viewing_records(self):
        tree=ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=("Id ", "name", "Surname", "DOB"))
        tree.grid(row=100, column=0, columnspan=100)
        tree.heading('#0', text='ID', anchor=W)
        tree.heading("#1", text='name', anchor=W)
        tree.heading("#2", text='Surname', anchor=W)
        tree.heading("#3", text='DOB', anchor=W)

        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete (element)
            query = 'SELECT * FROM Products '
            db_rows = self.run_query (query)
            for row in db_rows:
                self.tree.insert ('', 1, values=(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root=Tk()
        main=Main(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EnterProducts.viewing_records()` a `Treeview` is created and then bound to the *local* variable `tree`. Several lines later an attempt is made to access the tree using the instance attribute `self.tree` which refers to a different. non-existent, variable than the one that was created as a local variable.

If you want the tree to remain in the `EnterProducts` instance you need to treat it as an instance variable, i.e. bind it to `self.tree` when it is created. Otherwise, remove the `self.` from `self.tree` to treat it as a local variable.

Comment: sorry how would i bind it to self.tree

Comment: Use `self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=("Id ", "name", "Surname", "DOB"))` and then reference it with `self.tree` elsewhere. You might also like to specify the parent widget for the `Treeview` as the first argument to its constructor.

Comment: I'd be inclined to create the tree in `EnterProducts.__init__()` and then populate it in `viewing_records()`.